# Expanding exp(I*theta) using Euler's formula in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I want to expand ￼ [image] to `1 + cos(phi_x) + I*sin(phi_x)` without explicitly substituting for `exp(I*phi_x)` with SymPy. Can't find a way to do that.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sympy simplify Euler's formula not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69156752/sympy-simplify-eulers-formula-not-working)

Answer (score -1):

found the solution -
exp.rewrite(sym.sin) or expr.rewrite(sym.cos) works.