# Sympy simplify Euler's formula not working

Tags: sympy

I am doing my physics homework and tried to simplify an expression using the Euler formula. The minimal not-working example looks like this.

```
from sympy import *
x, phi = symbols("x varphi", real=True)

simplify(x * (E**(I*phi) + E**(-I*phi)))
```

My Jupiter notebook outputs the exact same thing back

[image: 1]

While the desired expression using the Euler formula is

[image: 2]

However, sympy actually knows how to use the Euler formula to represent the cosine function, because it outputs the simplified expression nicely when the x is removed:

```
simplify(E**(I*phi) + E**(-I*phi))
```

gives

[image: 3]

Since the distributive property of multiplication apply to complex numbers, I don't see why sympy can't figure out the desired simplification of the first expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be it is by design. As a workaround you can do

```
expr=x* (E**(I*phi) + E**(-I*phi))
expr.rewrite(cos)
```

which gives

```
2*x*cos(varphi)
```